# Read the result of a promise when it is in one line in the browser

Tags: javascript, logging

Consider this code:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject ) => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log("log1!")
        resolve({
            name: 'whatever',
            age: 17
        })
    }, 3000)
})

myPromise.then((data) => data.age) // breakpoint here
```

I want to log `data` in the browser. Breakpoint stops when the promise fires but not after it resolves so cannot check the value of `data`.
I tried "pretty print" icon in the browser `{}` but does not break the line of the promise `.then` so that I cannot add a breakpoint and check the result.

Is there any way to log `data` in the browser?

Comment: Do you just mean this?:  `myPromise.then((data) => console.log(data))`  It's not really clear to me what you're asking, the code shown demonstrates how to log something to the console and then asks how to log something else to the console.  Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: I cannot modify the code in the browser so I cannot add a `console.log`

Comment: You literally _can_ edit the code in the debugger though.

Comment: in the debugger? where?  May I edit the script in the browser? I am not in the debugger, the problem states its code already served to the browser.

Comment: In the Sources tab, where you have the code and can set breakpoints. Just type.

Comment: Breakpoint stops when the promise fires but not after it resolves so cannot check the value of data